# Only allow specific children Firebase Rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Under my `"allUsers"` node I'm trying to only allow new data entries to have the following structure:

```
"allUsers" {
   "$user1: {
     "name": "user1Name"
     "uid": "12345"
   }
}
```

I don't want any other values besides `"name"` and `"uid"`. I added a `"other": { ".validate": false }` rule under each `$user`, but for some reason the following write is denied:

[image: pic]

Can anybody help me understand why the write fails even though I only have a name and uid in the data?

Comment: Maybe it's because you are denying everything in `$other` by placing `".validate": false`

Comment: Exactly what @CraftedGaming said, you need to pass all path and subpath validations.

Comment: I posted a solution, you also should not be checking for `hasChildren()` in writes rules as they cascade. Let me know if you need me to elaborate, I'm in a helpful mood .

Answer (score 0):

Line 15 in your screenshot passed. It checks for `newData.child($user)` underneath `$user`. So, it looks like the write was to: `/allUsers/meow/meow/` (note repetition of username), which may be the source of the problem.

That might explain why lines 18 and 19 for `name` and `uid` have neither a pass nor a fail, and why line 20 fails, since `"meow"` is not a valid key underneath `$user`, even though it is a valid username.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass validation at all paths and subpaths. The variable `$other` is catching everything, including the paths you intend to allow. Instead write you rule as such.

```
"$path": {
  ".validate": "$path == 'name' || $path == 'uid'"
},
```